# Why the cubes spawn effect is not the same in the video tutorial?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The video tutorial:

[Object Pooling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdSmKaJvCoA&t=698s)

In the Hierarchy I have two empty GameObjects one named Object Pooler the seocnd named Cube Spawner.

In the Object Pooler is attached a script name ObjectPooler:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectPooler : MonoBehaviour
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Pool
    {
        public string tag;
        public GameObject prefab;
        public int size;
    }

    #region Singleton

    public static ObjectPooler Instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    #endregion

    public List<Pool> pools;
    public Dictionary<string, Queue<GameObject>> poolDictionary;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        poolDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Queue<GameObject>>();

        foreach(Pool pool in pools)
        {
            Queue<GameObject> objectPool = new Queue<GameObject>();

            for(int i = 0; i < pool.size; i++)
            {
                GameObject obj = Instantiate(pool.prefab);
                obj.SetActive(false);
                objectPool.Enqueue(obj);
            }

            poolDictionary.Add(pool.tag, objectPool);
        }
    }

    public GameObject SpawnFromPool(string tag, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation)
    {
        if(!poolDictionary.ContainsKey(tag))
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Pool with tag " + tag + " doesn't exist.");
            return null;
        }

        GameObject objectToSpawn = poolDictionary[tag].Dequeue();

        objectToSpawn.SetActive(true);
        objectToSpawn.transform.position = position;
        objectToSpawn.transform.rotation = rotation;

        IPooledObject pooledObj = objectToSpawn.GetComponent<IPooledObject>();

        if(pooledObj != null)
        {
            pooledObj.OnObjectSpawn();
        }

        poolDictionary[tag].Enqueue(objectToSpawn);

        return objectToSpawn;
    }
}
```

On the Cube Spawner attached a script name CubeSpawner:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    ObjectPooler objectPooler;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        objectPooler = ObjectPooler.Instance;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        objectPooler.SpawnFromPool("Cube", transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

And I have a Cube prefab with a Rigidbody component and a script name Cube:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Cube : MonoBehaviour , IPooledObject
{
    public float upForce = 1f;
    public float sideForce = .1f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public void OnObjectSpawn()
    {
        float xForce = Random.Range(-sideForce, sideForce);
        float yForce = Random.Range(upForce / 2f, upForce);
        float zForce = Random.Range(-sideForce, sideForce);

        Vector3 force = new Vector3(xForce, yForce, zForce);

        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = force;
    }
}
```

In the tutorial video the effect of the objects spawn is like this:

[image: The effect as it should be]

And this is the effect when I'm running the game in my editor:

[image: My effect]

The Rigidbody on the Cube Prefab I just attached it as it is I didn't change any of it's values.

Answer (score 1):

Could be because your cubes's rigidbodies and the ones in the tutorial don't have the same mass, therefore adding the same force would result in different results. Could you check that ?

Comment: I will check in few minutes when I will be back. Thanks.

Comment: I could also be a missing or too small gravity.

Comment: I found in the video that the cubes the Rigidbody settings: Mass = 1 Drag = 0.1 Angular Drag = 0.05 And Use Gravity is checked true. And the script Up Force = 25 and Side Force = 7 but still in my editor it's not the same it's like in the screenshot in my question.

Comment: Do you have something like this `Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, -1.0F, 0);` to set the gravity? Or go to `Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics` to set it manually.